# Runtime error - NZEC Non-zero exit code: This error has occurred because the program has exited after returning a different value from 0 to the shell

Tags: java, arrays

Problem
You are given an array  of size  that contains integers. Here,  is an even number. You are required to perform the following operations:

Divide the array of numbers in two equal halves
Note: Here, two equal parts of a test case are created by dividing the array into two equal parts.
Take the first digit of the numbers that are available in the first half of the array (first 50% of the test case)
Take the last digit of the numbers that are available in the second half of the array (second 50% of the test case)
Generate a number by using the digits that have been selected in the above steps
Your task is to determine whether the newly-generated number is divisible by .

Input format

First line: A single integer  denoting the size of array
Second line:  space-separated integers denoting the elements of array
Output format
If the newly-generated number is divisible by , then print . Otherwise, print .

Constraints

Sample Input
6
15478 8452 8232 874 985 4512
Sample Output
OUI
Time Limit: 1
Memory Limit: 256
Source Limit:
Explanation
The first digit of 15478 is 1.
The first digit of 8452 is 8.
The first digit of 8232 is 8.
The last digit of 874 is 4.
The last digit of 985 is 5.
The last digit of 4512 is 2.
The newly generated number will be 188452 which is divisible by 11.

[Java Code working in eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3lhI.png)

[Error in Hackerearth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZWAk.png)

Comment: Please see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822). It looks like there's an output log in Hackerearth that might tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Displayed when a program exits and returns a value other than 0 to the shell

In C/C++
You forget to add "return 0" at the end of the program. Your program
threw an exception which was not caught Your program is trying to
allocate too much memory in a vector

In interpreted languages (for e.g. Python)
Usually means that your program has either crashed or raised an
uncaught exception Many runtime errors or you are trying to return different variables(in my case).

Comment: Read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831) before pasting AI generated answers.